# No annotations present when reflecting a method using class.getDeclaredMethod

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, java-8

I'm writing some unit tests using *reflection*, and I'm having trouble retrieving annotations from method parameters.

I declared this interface:

```
private interface Provider {
    void mock(@Email String email);
}
```

And I'm trying to reflect this method, as follows:

```
Class stringClass = String.class;
Method method = Provider.class.getDeclaredMethod("mock", String.class);
AnnotatedType annotatedType = method.getAnnotatedParameterTypes()[0];
Annotation annotation = annotatedType.getAnnotation(Annotation.class);
```

I'm expecting that `annotation` variable holds an instance of `@Email` annotation, but instead, its value is `null`.

Even this simple check returns `false`:

```
method.isAnnotationPresent(Email.class)
```

So, how can I retrieve the annotations for an specific param when *reflecting* a method?

### Updated

It seems that in order to retrieve the parameters annotation I need to call `method.getParameterAnnotations()`. But the problem with this is that I don't know what annotations belong to what methods.

Comment: If `@Email` is already retained at `RUNTIME`, please post a [MCVE] that reproduces your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a distinction between the Java 8 *type annotations* and the (since Java 5) *parameter* annotations. The crucial thing about type annotations, is, that you have to declare the possibility of using your annotation as type annotation explicitly.

Consider the following example:

```
public class AnnoTest {
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @interface Email {}

    void example(@Email String arg) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        Method method=AnnoTest.class.getDeclaredMethod("example", String.class);
        System.out.println("parameter type annotations:");
        AnnotatedType annotatedType = method.getAnnotatedParameterTypes()[0];
        //Annotation annotation = annotatedType.getAnnotation(Annotation.class);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(annotatedType.getAnnotations()));
        System.out.println("parameter annotations:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(method.getParameterAnnotations()[0]));
    }
}
```

it will print

```
parameter type annotations:
[]
parameter annotations:
[@AnnoTest$Email()]
```

In this case the annotation is a property of the *parameter*.

Now change it to (note the `@Target`)

```
public class AnnoTest {
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
    @interface Email {}

    void example(@Email String arg) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        Method method=AnnoTest.class.getDeclaredMethod("example", String.class);
        System.out.println("parameter type annotations:");
        AnnotatedType annotatedType = method.getAnnotatedParameterTypes()[0];
        //Annotation annotation = annotatedType.getAnnotation(Annotation.class);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(annotatedType.getAnnotations()));
        System.out.println("parameter annotations:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(method.getParameterAnnotations()[0]));
    }
}
```

which will print

```
parameter type annotations:
[@AnnoTest$Email()]
parameter annotations:
[]
```

instead. So now, the annotation is a feature of the parameter *type*, i.e. `String`. Conceptionally, the parameter type of the method is now `@Email String` (which seems to be the most logical choice, as it allows declaring types like `List<@Email String>`, but you have to understand how these new type annotations work and it doesn’t work together with pre-Java 8 libraries).

Care must be taken when enabling an annotation for both, parameters and type use, as this can create ambiguous annotations.
If that happens, the compiler will record the annotations for both, the parameter and the type, e.g.
when you change the target in the example to `@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.PARAMETER})`, it will print

```
parameter type annotations:
[@AnnoTest$Email()]
parameter annotations:
[@AnnoTest$Email()]
```

similar issues may arise at method return types, resp. field types when enabling an annotation for “type use” and methods, resp. fields.

Answer (score 3):

If you want annotation to be visible during program execution, you need to annotate it with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`:

```
private interface Provider {
    void mock(@Email String email);
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Email{}

@Test
public void test_annotation_existence() throws NoSuchMethodException {

    Method method = Provider.class.getDeclaredMethod("mock", String.class);

    Annotation[] firstParameterAnnotationsArray = method.getParameterAnnotations()[0];
    boolean isAnnotationPresent = isAnnotationPresent(firstParameterAnnotationsArray, Email.class);

    Assert.assertTrue("Annotation not present!", isAnnotationPresent);

}

private boolean isAnnotationPresent(Annotation[] annotationsArray, Class clazz) {
    if (annotationsArray == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please pass a non-null array of Annotations.");
    for(int i = 0; i < annotationsArray.length; i++ ) {
        if (annotationsArray[i].annotationType().equals(clazz))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Email is already annotated with Retentition annotation. I should have point out that.

Comment: Take a look at the rest of the code please.
The `method.getParameterAnnotations()[0]` does not return `AnnotatedType` but the array of `Annotation` which you can cycle through.